# Vanilla Javascript: Infinite Image Marquee

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so I must create an infinite auto-scrolling horizontal image marquee using vanilla JS. I have the following code:

```js
//if(painkiller<14){painkiller++;} else{painkiller=0;backup2()}
var speed = 5;
var exeggcute = true;
var painkiller = 0;
var marquix = document.getElementById("marquis");
var backup = "";
var coquus = 0;
for (var painkiller = 0; painkiller < 15; painkiller++) {
  backup += "<img class='slide' src='" + ImgArray[painkiller].src + "' width='" + ImgArray[painkiller].width + "'>";
}
marquix.innerHTML = backup;

function riverflow() {
  marquix.scrollLeft += 5;
  if (marquix.children[0].getBoundingClientRect().left <= (marquix.children[0].width * -1)) {
    marquix.appendChild(marquix.children[0]);
    //marquix.getBoundingClientRect().left=0;
    //marquix.children[0].style.transform="translateX(133px)"
  }
}

//function backup2(){marquix.innerHTML=backup;}
setInterval('riverflow()', 50);
exeggcute = true;
```

```html
<head>
<script>
  var ImgArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    ImgArray[i] = new Image();
    ImgArray[i].src = "imgx/imagen" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
    ImgArray[i].width = 133;
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="marquis">

  </div>
</body>
```

Basically I'm creating the image chain, then filling with it the innerHTML of a div, then assigning said div to a variable, and finally calling a repetitive function through setInterval(). Now, what that function does is a simple scroll to the left and - when the first image is completely out of the viewport - use appendChild to rip the first child element or img from the image chain then put it at the end of it. So no image overcharge is produced and the marquee uses the same 15 element once and again.

Here's my problem, though: when the appendChild function fires, the image that's out of the viewport is removed, however, the next image in line - as well as the rest of the chain - does not preserve its current position, and is instead forcefully scrolled to fill the gap left by the then-first image that's now at the end. Thus, the condition of the appendChild (which was the first children of the div being completely out of the viewport) becomes true and activates the function - leading the whole marquee to slide non-stop and out of control, as the appendChild is firing continuously.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Take a look at [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations).

Comment: It must be done exclusively using pure JS, no libraries, no jquery, no CSS in that element.

Comment: If this is a homework, a satisfying animation is probably possible. If the requirement is "absolutely no CSS", then I think you've to go with window width and non-breaking spaces additional to the image tag.

Comment: It's a requirement of the project, in case it was something I wanted to do on my own, I'd use CSS animations undoubtly. The thing is, I can't. I know I'm referencing the CSS through JS and that's why the styles are changing, what I meant is I can't use animations, but instead make the animations using DOM and JS. I can't just give it some CSS class with animations.

Comment: OK. Please explain the possible use of the CSS with few words in the question, that might prevent more similar comments to mine to be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

- You will need to reset the scrollLeft to 0 on the same moment that you switch the images.
- You will need to add some element (another img for example at the begining) it could be all white or transparent. That image will be always there, before the firstone visible. When you remove the other image this auxiliar image need to be wider (change the width) to fill the gap, so add to its width the width of the removed image each time you remove one.
- Or you can change the marginLeft of the leftmost image with marquix.children[0].style.marginLeft = n + "px";

Comment: Thx man, I ended up using translateX to force the img position to where it should be. The only problem being, it increases ad infinitum, but I guess there's no problem. However, I'd like to fix it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I came up with, but as I said, the translateX() parameter increases ad infinitum.

```html
<script>
var ImgArray=[];

for (var i=0; i<15; i++){
ImgArray[i]= new Image();
ImgArray[i].src= "imgx/imagen"+(i+1)+".jpg";
ImgArray[i].width=133; 
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="marquis">

<script>
//if(painkiller<14){painkiller++;} else{painkiller=0;backup2()}

var exeggcute= true;
var painkiller=0;
var marquix = document.getElementById("marquis");

var backup=""; var coquus=0;
for(var painkiller =0;painkiller<15;painkiller++){
backup+="<img class='slide' src='"+ImgArray[painkiller].src+"' width='"+ImgArray[painkiller].width+"'>";
}

marquix.innerHTML=backup;
var slidin=133;


function riverflow(){

marquix.scrollLeft+=10;
if (marquix.children[0].getBoundingClientRect().left<=(marquix.children[0].width*-1) && exeggcute){
marquix.appendChild(marquix.children[0]);
marquix.getBoundingClientRect().left=0; 
for (var j=0; j<15; j++){
marquix.children[j].setAttribute("style","transform: translateX("+slidin+"px)")
}
slidin+=133;
}

}

//function backup2(){marquix.innerHTML=backup;}
setInterval('riverflow()',50);
exeggcute=true;

</script>
```